# RPG embedded SQL set option commit=*CS

Tags: db2, db2-400, rpgle

In free form RPG using embedded SQL, I specified this for my SQL options:

```
exec sql
 set option commit=*CS,
 datfmt=*iso,
 closqlcsr=*endmod;
```

If I specify `commit=*CS`, do I need to specify `WITH CS` on my SQL select statement or is that assumed since I specified it in the set option?

If I specify `commit=*none`, and then specify `WITH CS` on my SQL select statement will the `WITH CS` take effect since on my set option commit I said `*none`?

Answer (score 1):

the `set option` statement sets the default for all statements in the module.

That default can be overridden by the `WITH` clause on an individual statement.

So with

```
exec sql
 set option commit=*CS,
 datfmt=*iso,
 closqlcsr=*endmod;
```

A statement without a `WITH` clause will use commitment control and an isolation level of cursor stability.  A statement with `WITH NC` will not use commitment control and a statement with `WITH RS` will use commitment control and an isolation level read stability.

Note: `closqlcsr=*endmod` will hurt performance.  It's usually used as a band-aid for poorly designed and/or outdated applications.

Comment: `closqlcsr=*endmod` might or might not hurt performance. It might be best to specify it, but we can't tell from the OP yet. It's very often best not to specify it.